# What is wrong with this objective-C string manipulation? trying to parse a string and return different characters

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

I'm trying to take an input string and return a new string that is encoded/decoded based on a dictionary that I created.  I have tried the below code using instance variables and local variables.  I am having a problem using the for loop.  I get out of scope errors.  When I use an instance variable for newText, I get a exec bad address when I try to assign the dictionaries value to it. When I declare newText in the method, I get out of scope errors.

```
- (NSString *) decodeText:(NSString *)text {
     NSString *parseString = text;
     NSLog(@"Letterdictionary = %@",lettersDictionary);
     NSInteger y = [parseString length];
     NSMutableString *newText = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[parseString length]];
     for (int x=0; x < y; x++) {
          NSRange Range = NSMakeRange(x, 1);
          NSString *myChar = [parseString substringWithRange:Range];
          NSLog(@"Mychar =:%@",myChar);
          [newText appendString:[lettersDictionary objectForKey:myChar]];
          NSLog(@"newtext=%@",newText);

      }
 NSLog(@"NewText=%@",newText);
 return newText;
}
```

here is the output from the debugger:

```
2010-08-21 07:59:27.151 GeoWordCalc[77460:207] Letterdictionary = {
    N = A;
    O = B;
    P = C;
}
2010-08-21 07:59:47.891 GeoWordCalc[77460:207] Mychar =:A
2010-08-21 07:59:49.707 GeoWordCalc[77460:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString appendString:]: nil  argument'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x023df919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0252d5de objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02398078 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   CoreFoundation                      0x02397fea +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
4   Foundation                          0x000a585a mutateError + 156
5   GeoWordCalc                         0x000050aa -[WordDecoder decodeText:] + 330
6   GeoWordCalc                         0x00004cec -[DecoderViewController textFieldCharacterEntered] + 157
7   UIKit                               0x003424b0 -[UIControl(D  eprecated) sendAction:toTarget:forEvent:] + 67
8   UIKit                               0x00344d81 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEventMask:withEvent:] + 525
9   UIKit                               0x0034a051 -[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] + 258
10  UIKit                               0x003597f3 -[UIFieldEditor webViewDidChange:] + 76
11  Foundation                          0x00022c1d _nsnote_callback + 145
12  CoreFoundation                      0x023b7cf9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0233711a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
14  Foundation                          0x000187c2 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0235042d __invoking___ + 29
16  CoreFoundation                      0x02350301 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 145
17  WebCore                             0x02e6277a _ZL19SendDelegateMessageP12NSInvocation + 602
18  WebKit                              0x03c0b72f _ZN15WebEditorClient24respondToChangedContentsEv + 63
19  WebCore                             0x02ee889c _ZN7WebCore6Editor14appliedEditingEN3WTF10PassRefPtrINS_11EditCommandEEE + 460
20  WebCore                             0x036bdb9b _ZN7WebCore13TypingCommand24typingAddedToOpenCommandENS0_14ETypingCommandE + 75
21  WebCore                             0x02ee312f _ZN7WebCore13TypingCommand28insertTextRunWithoutNewlinesERKNS_6StringEb + 159
22  WebCore                             0x02ee306b _ZN7WebCore13TypingCommand10insertTextERKNS_6StringEb + 331
23  WebCore                             0x02ee2eb6 _ZN7WebCore13TypingCommand7doApplyEv + 182
24  WebCore                             0x02ee2c58 _ZN7WebCore11EditCommand5applyEv + 248
25  WebCore                             0x02ee1c95 _ZN7WebCore13TypingCommand10insertTextEPNS_8DocumentERKNS_6StringERKNS_16VisibleSelectionEbb + 1525
26  WebCore                             0x02ee1058 _ZN7WebCore6Editor33insertTextWithoutSendingTextEventERKNS_6StringEbPNS_5EventE + 1048
27  WebCore                             0x02ee0c15 _ZN7WebCore12EventHandler28defaultTextInputEventHandlerEPNS_9TextEventE + 197
28  WebCore                             0x02eb4548 _ZN7WebCore4Node19defaultEventHandlerEPNS_5EventE + 152
29  WebCore                             0x02eb42a8 _ZN7WebCore4Node20dispatchGenericEventEN3WTF10PassRefPtrINS_5EventEEE + 1016
30  WebCore                             0x02eb3e39 _ZN7WebCore4Node13dispatchEventEN3WTF10PassRefPtrINS_5EventEEE + 217
31  WebCore                             0x02ee0ae0 _ZN7WebCore11EventTarget13dispatchEventEN3WTF10PassRefPtrINS_5EventEEERi + 112
32  WebCore                             0x02ee07e1 _ZN7WebCore12EventHandler20handleTextInputEventERKNS_6StringEPNS_5EventEbb + 225
33  WebCore                             0x02ee06f9 _ZN7WebCore6Editor10insertTextERKNS_6StringEPNS_5EventE + 57
34  WebKit                              0x03c0af07 -[WebHTMLView(WebNSTextInputSupport) insertText:] + 951
35  WebCore                             0x02ee0594 -[WAKResponder tryToPerform:with:] + 84
36  WebKit                              0x03c0a9b3 -[WebView(WebViewEditingActions) _performResponderOperation:with:] + 147
37  WebKit                              0x03c0a910 -[WebView(WebViewEditingActions) insertText:] + 48
38  UIKit                               0x003f32db -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:fromVariantKey:] + 3251
39  UIKit                               0x003f4a1a -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 1918
40  UIKit                               0x005151c0 -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar sendStringAction:forKey:] + 684
41  UIKit                               0x005199ba -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar touchUp:] + 2556
42  UIKit                               0x0040b9a3 -[UIKeyboardLayout touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 550
43  UIKit                               0x002dc2ff -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
44  UIKit                               0x002be1ec -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
45  UIKit                               0x002c2ac4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7495
46  GraphicsServices                    0x02c45afa PurpleEventCallback + 1578
47  CoreFoundation                      0x023c0dc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
48  CoreFoundation                      0x02321737 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
49  CoreFoundation                      0x0231e9c3 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
50  CoreFoundation                      0x0231e280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
51  CoreFoundation                      0x0231e1a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
52  GraphicsServices                    0x02c442c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
53  GraphicsServices                    0x02c4438d GSEventRun + 115
54  UIKit                               0x002c6b58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
55  GeoWordCalc                         0x000027c4 main + 102
56  GeoWordCalc                         0x00002755 start + 53
```

)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: Those errors would help if given here...

Answer (score 0):

Okay..so after a night's sleep and more debugging I figured out that I lettersDictionary was returning a null value.  It seems I build the dictionary backwards...sorry and thanks.

Comment: You could have just closed the question.

Comment: Thanks for the info ... I haven't closed my own non-questions before, didn't know this was possible *heading off to check my old questions*